# Write to mail addresses of the current message

Tags: thunderbird

Many mail users use "Reply" just to get the To: line filled quickly and correctly. They forget to change the subject and to remove the headers References: / In-Reply-To: which makes the whole discussion threads quite confusing. Hence, I am looking for a quick way in Thunderbird to compose a new message only filling the To: header. This could be named "Write on new subject" or "Fork" or similar. An add-on solution would be acceptable, too.

Answer (score 1):

Right-clicking the sender's email address and choosing "Compose Message To" should do.

Comment: Thanks. But this is only a partial solution because it seems limited to 1:1 conversations (i.e. without any CC).